# For SEO, can I just serve a static HTML alternative version alongside my Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, seo, javascript-framework

I have a single page AngularJS app and I want the initial page render to contain all relevant info as HTML so it is crawlable with JavaScript disabled.

For simplicity I was thinking of just adding an alternative HTML version which is hidden when the Angular app loads.

```
<div>
    <!-- Static page content for crawlers, hidden when Angular app loads -->
</div>

<!-- Angular app -->
```

What are the drawbacks to this approach (serving a complete pre-rendered copy)? The angular app draws data from a JavaScript object rendered as part of the page and I am happy to live with the data being sent twice.

Comment: You could take the accessibility tag off, it isn't an accessibility issue per-se, it's SEO.

Answer (score 3):

Google have defined a specification that lets you serve snapshots of your page's HTML *after* all necessary Javascript has run to search engines.

This is supported by Google, Bing, Yandex and even some social network bots: Here are the details of who supports it: http://blog.ajaxsnapshots.com/2013/11/googles-crawlable-ajax-specification.html

Implementing this youself is a fair bit of work, so several companies including https://ajaxsnapshots.com (who I work for) provide it as a service that you can plug into your web server without making any changes to your app.

Comment: as it seems ajaxsnapshots is down, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

A search engine bot doesn't really care whether the content is hidden/ visible.

The search engine bot would crawl through almost the entire content of the page.

Therefore its highly recommended to have only the relevant content in place.